# How to specify host.json when setting maxAutoRenewDuration and functionTimeout as unlimited in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How to specify host.json when setting maxAutoRenewDuration and functionTimeout as unlimited in Azure Functions?

Should I specify minus one?

```
     "functionTimeout": "-1"
```

```
     "maxAutoRenewDuration": "-1"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Premium` and `Dedicated (App Service)`, the value of functionTimeout is `-1` indicates unbounded execution. `Premium plan` execution is only guaranteed for 60 minutes, but technically unbounded.

**So you can specify the value of `functionTimeout` as `-1`.**

I did not find the relevant configuration instructions for `maxAutoRenewDuration` in your link, but I refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings), the document does not indicate that you can use `-1`, **so I recommend that you specify a specific and large enough value for maxAutoRenewDuration.**

Of course, you can also try to specify the value of `maxAutoRenewDuration` as -1